# Replacing null values of a dataframe with a sub-string of another column value

Tags: python, data-science, str-replace

I'm trying to replaced null values of a dataframe with a value of another column value.

```
Product name  | Brand   | Rate | Qty  |
--------------|---------|------|------|
samsung note  |   Null  |  5   |  1   |
Nokia Lumia   |   Nokia |  2   |  2   |
One Plus 8    |   Null  |  3   |  3   |
```

How to get this output?
I want to fill the missing value on **Brand** based on value on keyword in **Product Name**. The result I need is like:

```
if value in Product Name = Samsung Note then value in Brand= "samsung"
if value in Product Name = One Plus 8 then value in Brand= "One Plus"
Product name  | Brand   | Rate | Qty  |
--------------|---------|------|------|
samsung note  |  Samsung|  5   |  1   |
Nokia Lumia   |   Nokia |  2   |  2   |
One Plus 8    | One Plus|  3   |  3   |
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
df['column_you_want'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['column_you_want'] if row['column_you_want'] else row['column_string'][start_substring:end_substring])
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I didn't saw your pictures, but this should work... just change how do you get the substring (with a split for example)